# AJAX request giving 404 from mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm writing a test mobile app using asp.net, jquery mobile and phonegap.  I have a simple form in which you enter an year and click submit. Ajax call is made to results.aspx.cs page on the server which returns the result and displayed on 2nd page.

When I run mobile app on local server I'm getting 404 error -- responseText: "Cannot POST /results.aspx.cs/IsLeapYear↵", status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}.

index.html page contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var SectedCityCode, URL, prov;
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
                <form id="checkyear" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
                    <label for="txtYear">Enter the year:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="txtYear" id="txtYear" value="" />
                    <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end of first page -->
<!-- start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Welcome Page</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p id="result"></p>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Page footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end of second page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js contains the following:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function () {
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function () { // catch the form's submit event
    if ($('#txtYear').val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://website.com/results.aspx.cs/IsLeapYear',
            data: '{ year: "' + txtYear.value + '"}',
            type: 'post',
            async: 'true',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status) {
                    result.val = "Leap Year";
                    $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                } else {
                    result.val = "Not a Leap Year";                        
                }
            },
            error: function (request, error) {                    
                // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
    }
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
});
```

results.aspx.cs contains following:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static bool IsLeapYear(int year) 
{ 
  return DateTime.IsLeapYear(year); 
}
```

Can someone tell me what mistake am I making?

Joe

Comment: Is your website accessible through alternate means? Try using an HTTP client to test your request header and body at your URL, this is a very helful tool in these situations http://www.swensensoftware.com/im-only-resting

Comment: Nice tool. When I do http://169.254.51.156:3000/results.aspx.cs with GET I get status 200 OK but with POST I get 404 Not Found. Any idea why?

Comment: is its works in browser /

Comment: @citm09 If you are unable to `POST` normally I'd check your local environment settings, perhaps your web.config disallows `POST` headers https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819267

Comment: as per the KB, I added lines for POST and GET in web.config but still the same error message.

Comment: I just posted my entire index.html file.

Comment: I've made some preogress, now I'm getting error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://somewebsite/results.aspx.cs/IsLeapYear. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://169.254.0.2:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

http://169.254.0.2:3000 is a localserver that Phonegap Desktop is running on.